# Lua - My documents path and file creation date

Tags: lua

I'm planning to do a program with Lua that will first of all read specific files
and get information from those files. So my first question is whats the "my documents" path name? I have searched a lot of places, but I'm unable to find anything. My second question is how can I use the first four letters of a file name to see which one is the newest made?

Finding the files in "my documents" then find the newest created file and read it.
The reading part shouldn't be a problem, but navigating to "my documents" and finding the newest created file in a folder.

Comment: Can you please clarify your questions? 1) Do you mean a specific place on a Windows computer (that's what it sounds like to me, but I'm not very familiar with Windows; maybe it will be clear to others). 2) How would you ever be able to tell order of file creation based on file names? Were the files named in some specific way that guarantees that?

Comment: C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents but USERNAME for me would be Jakob, but what about for others? arent there something that works everywhere? and I can see the newest file by a date added at the end of it, even time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, depends how robust you want your script to be. You could use Lua's builtin os.getenv() to get a variety of environment vars related to user, such as USERNAME, USERPROFILE, HOMEDRIVE, HOMEPATH. Example:

```
username = os.getenv('USERNAME')
dir = 'C:\\users\\' .. username .. '\\Documents'
```

For the second question, there is no builtin mechanism in Windows to have the file creation or modification timestamp as part of the filename. You could read the creation or modification *timestamp*, via a C extension you create or using an existing Lua library like lfs. Or you could read the contents of a folder and parse the filenames if they were named according to the pattern you mention. Again there is nothing built into Lua to do this, you would either use os.execute() or lfs or, again, your own C extension module, or combinations of these.

Comment: thanks! well I though I could get around the .dll thing or anything with c/c++

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "get around the .dll thing or anything with c/c+": you build .dll using c/c++. I don't think it is clear based on your comment whether this answers your question or not. If it does, please mark it as accepted, otherwise please comment clearly what is lacking so we can help.

Comment: I got it all sorted out

Comment: @SpecialLUANewbie Great. Feel free to pay forward by posting what worked (via a comment or an answer) so others can benefit from everyone's efforts.